# Calling ASMX from Powershell

Tags: powershell, asmx

I have a simple asmx web service

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
    public string HelloWorld(Person person) {
        return "Hello World " + person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName;
    }
}

public class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling this from powershell like

```
cls
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri 'http://localhost:10875/WebService1.asmx' -UseDefaultCredential
$person = new-object ("Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1calhost_10875_WebService1_asmx.Person")
$person.FirstName = "foo"
$person.LastName = "bar"

$s = $proxy.HelloWorld($person)
Write-Host $s
```

But I don't like the funny namespace in order to access the Person class.

is there a better way of accessing the Person class without using something funny like WebServiceProxy1calhost_10875_WebService1_asmx?

Can I discover the Person class from the $proxy object?

Edit:

I changed my powershell code to

```
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri 'http://localhost:10875/WebService1.asmx' -Namespace "com.abhi" -Class "Proxy" -UseDefaultCredential
$proxy | get-member -type method
$person = new-object ("com.abhi.Proxy.Person")
$person.FirstName = "foo"
$person.LastName = "bar"

$s = $proxy.HelloWorld($person)
Write-Host $s
```

but now I get an error

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [com.abhi.Proxy.Person]: make sure the assembly containing this type is load
ed.
At C:\Users\srabhi_adm\Documents\SP2010InfobarrierException.ps1:6 char:21
+ $person = new-object <<<<  ("com.abhi.Proxy.Person")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Property 'FirstName' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\srabhi_adm\Documents\SP2010InfobarrierException.ps1:7 char:9
+ $person. <<<< FirstName = "foo"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (FirstName:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Property 'LastName' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\srabhi_adm\Documents\SP2010InfobarrierException.ps1:8 char:9
+ $person. <<<< LastName = "bar"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (LastName:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Exception calling "HelloWorld" with "1" argument(s): "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server 
was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
 of an object.
   at SP2010InfobarrierExceptions.WebService1.HelloWorld(Person person) in c:\users\srabhi_adm\documents\v
isual studio 2010\Projects\SP2010InfobarrierExceptions\SP2010InfobarrierExceptions\WebService1.asmx.cs:lin
e 22
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---"
At C:\Users\srabhi_adm\Documents\SP2010InfobarrierException.ps1:10 char:23
+ $s = $proxy.HelloWorld <<<< ($person)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
$person = new-object ("com.abhi.Proxy.Person")
```

to this:

```
$person = new-object ("com.abhi.Person")
```

The `-Namespace` parameter specifies the namespace where types from the WSDL will be generated, so if your WSDL declares the `Person` type, it will be available in that namespace. The `-Class` argument specifies the proxy class name, by default `"MyClass" + random` (similarily to the namespace). You don't generally concern yourself with the proxy <del>class or its name, so you can leave it on default by simply not specifying this parameter</del> name, it can really be any valid class name as long, but you need to specify it along with `-Namespace`.

Complete demo call from PowerShell:

```
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri "http://localhost:57633/WebSite1/Service.asmx?WSDL" -namespace "com.example" -class "MyProxyClass"

$person = New-Object "com.example.Person";
$person.FirstName = "MyFirstName";
$person.LastName = "MyLastName";

$proxy.HelloWorld($person);
```

Comment: still got the error `Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "com.abhi.Person", for "HelloWorld" to type "com.abhi.Person": "C
annot convert the "com.abhi.Person" value of type "com.abhi.Person" to type "com.abhi.Person"."
At C:\Users\srabhi_adm\Documents\SP2010InfobarrierException.ps1:10 char:23
+ $s = $proxy.HelloWorld <<<< ($person)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument`

Comment: Ok, I've created a new webservice based on your code and it worked. I'm editing my answer to include the complete PowerShell part, maybe you'll spot some difference with your code? For what it's worth, I'm using PowerShell 4.0 from the ISE.

Comment: Actually, after researching this topic further I have found several hints to a bug (?): when you specify `-Namespace`, but omit `-Class`, `New-WebServiceProxy` will generate a randomly named proxy class, so when you repeatedly run the code the namespace will get polluted with multiple declarations of the same `Person` class. When you also specify the class name, the declaration gets properly replaced. I'm editing my answer with this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem albeit in a crooked way.

The approach above continued to give me errors. so what I did was I created a method in my web service like

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public Person GetEmptyPerson() {
    return new Person();
}
```

Now rather than call new in my client code. I just call this method and get the Person object. this works but involves one extra round trip to the server.

Anyway. my code doesn't require blazing performance so the overhead of one extra call is fine.